# How to add uv to a mesh with 4 or 8 vertices in blender API using smart_project function

Tags: uv

I am trying to write an script which adds UV maps to different meshes in a scene using smart_project() function, and while the code works for some of the mesh objects, it fails for some others. The meshes for which this process fails seem to have either 4 or 8 vertices. I really appreciate it if someone could explain what is going wrong or how to fix this issue.
Here is the code:

```
bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath=orig_obj_path, use_edges=True,use_smooth_groups=True,                                 use_split_objects=True, use_split_groups=True,use_groups_as_vgroups=False,use_image_search=True)
context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
vl = context.view_layer
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
for obj in scene.objects:
    # try:

    if (obj.type == 'MESH'):

        if obj.name == 'Cube':
            bpy.data.objects[obj.name].select_set(True)
            bpy.ops.object.delete()
            continue
        print("the number of vertices: ", len(obj.data.vertices), "name: ", obj.name)
        # if len(obj.data.vertices) < 9:
        #     bpy.data.objects[obj.name].select_set(True)
        #     bpy.ops.object.delete()
        #     continue
        vl.objects.active = obj
        obj.select_set(True)
        print(obj.name)
        lm =  obj.data.uv_layers.get("LightMap")
        if not lm:
            lm = obj.data.uv_layers.new(name="LightMap")
        lm.active = True
        bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
        bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT') # for all faces
        bpy.ops.uv.smart_project(angle_limit=66, island_margin = 0.02)
        bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
        obj.select_set(False)

bpy.ops.export_scene.obj(filepath=out_path,
                                 group_by_material=True,
                                 keep_vertex_order=True,
                                 use_normals=True, use_uvs=True,
                                 use_materials=True)
```

The following is the error message I am receiving:

> the number of vertices:  59 name:  mesh1_mesh1-geometry
> mesh1_mesh1-geometry
> the number of vertices:  4 name:  mesh2_mesh2-geometry
> mesh2_mesh2-geometry
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "test_blender.py", line 94, in 
> bpy.ops.uv.smart_project(angle_limit=66, island_margin = 0.02)
> File "/lib/python3.9/site-packages/3.1/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 132, in **call**
> ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
> RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.uv.smart_project.poll() failed, context is incorrect

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It would help if you could cut and paste your code and any error message into your question.

Comment: I updated my question with the code and the error message.

Comment: the angle limit should be in radians, check [the manual](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.uv.html#bpy.ops.uv.smart_project), also test smart_project operator without any parameters... other than that script seems to work for me, at least with blender meshes, didn't try the obj import thing

Comment: or you mean objects with no faces, just vertices... in that case it will fail, you should check if your object has a suitable mesh, something like 'if len(object.data.polygons): '

Comment: Thanks for the response, yes it seems that there are only vertices and not polygons for the mesh crashing the script. Then would that be safe to delete such objects from the scene?